# What is ref struct in definition site

Tags: c#, struct, ref, c#-7.0

I think I've heard a term "ref like struct" in GitHub some time ago.

Now that I have my hands on latest C# version (7.3), I could finally test it my self. So this seems to be a valid code:

```
public ref struct MyStruct
{
    int x;
}
```

I know what are ref locals and ref returns as there is documentation about that. But I could not find documentation about ref struct.

---

Ref structs can not be used on auto properties or fields. They can not be cast to object either. These were empirical findings.

With "Span" background that new c# gave me recently I guessed that ref struct is a stack only struct. That is an struct that never goes on heap. But im not 100% sure.

Im pretty sure there should be a documentation about this but I failed to find it.

Comment: Yes. But term ref here seems to have different meaning. Struct is not necessairly passed by reference (what first came to my mind) but it seems it forces struct to only reside on stack.

Comment: It indicates that struct accesses managed memory directly and must always be stack allocated. It is new feature introduced in C# 7.2.

Comment: Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types#ref-struct-type

Comment: Related proposal on the official github repository: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.2/span-safety.md

Comment: It's just keyword for compile code constrictions to help constrict the coding rules. What you might think otherwise to be a great idea, and doom the world to nuclear winter when your idea executed in real world ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After some research, I stumbled upon this article on [Compile time enforcement of safety for ref-like types in C# 7.2](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/06/CSharp-7.2).

> This C# feature is also known as “interior pointer” or “ref-like types”. The proposal is to allow the compiler to require that certain types such as `Span<T>` only appear on the stack.

The site also states the benefits of doing so, mainly concerning garbage collection and stack allocation.

---

Using ref-like types also brings some restrictions with it such as:

- ref-like type cannot be a type of an array element
- ref-like type cannot be used as a generic type argument
- ref-like variable cannot be boxed
- ref-like type cannot be a field of ordinary not ref-like type
- ref-like types cannot implement interfaces
- indirect restrictions, such as disallowed use of ref-like types in async methods, which are really a result of disallowing ref-like typed fields.

This limits them to be used for parameters, local variables, and in some cases return values.

---

There also exists an [official documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types#ref-struct-type), as @UnholySheep pointed out in the comments.

Comment: `ref struct` basically instructs the compiler to not allow boxing for the declared value type. Boxing is the process of moving a value type to the heap. `ref struct` is guaranteed to never leave the stack.

Answer (score 17):

This addition to **C# 7.2** is not really a ***feature*** in the sense of adding or enabling any new capability in the so-marked value-type itself, Rather, it allows the developer to declare or publish a specific ***restriction*** which governs the allowable use of that type everywhere else.

> [edit: see [**span-safety**](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.2/span-safety.md#language-constraints) at the github/dotnet site]

So instead of considering what `ref struct` designation gives the end-user of the struct, consider how it benefits the author. Adding any restriction on external use logically entails a related guarantee that the `ref struct` thus assumes, so the effect of the keyword is to empower or *"license"* the `ref struct` to do things that require those specific guarantees.

The point is that it's an *indirect* benefit, because the kinds of operations that are typically considered licensed by `ref struct` are basically none of the keyword's concern, and could be implemented and attempted, perhaps successfully even, by wily code anywhere, regardless of the `ref struct` marking (or not).

So much for the theoretical part. In reality, what is the "wily code" **use-case** that so existentially de­pends on the additional guarantees, even to the extreme point of accepting all the accompanying limitations? Essentially, it's the ability for a `struct` to **expose a managed reference to itself** or one of its fields.

Normally, **C#** enforces strong restrictions against the `this` reference leaking out of any instance method of a `struct`:

**`error CS8170: Struct members cannot return 'this' or other instance members by reference`**

The compiler has to be certain that there's virtually no possibility for the `this` pointer of a struct to leak out of the context where it "sits." This is possible, quite likely, or even inevitable for any struct instance that exists within in a GC object, or has been temporarily boxed for the purpose of calling one of its instance methods.

> *<sup>***note:*** When anticipated, such cases can be controlled-for in advance by associating a `GetPinnableReference` GC instance relative to which the managed pointer to the `struct` (or its interior) might be taken. Explicit pinning is the strictest and best-known technique, but there are also less heavy-handed options such as so-called *managed tracking references*, which are one of the most amazing under-recognized features of .NET... But these all add overhead, and in most situations, given that you're using value types in the first place, reducing the amount of cruft is desirable.</sup>*

With all the `ref` enhancements in recent years, **C#** now goes to even further lengths to detect and disallow `this` from escaping. For example, in addition to the above, we now have:

**`error CS8157: Cannot return 'x' by reference because it was initialized to a value that cannot be returned by reference`**

and related errors such as...

**`error CS8374: Cannot ref-assign 'foo' to 'p' because 'foo' has a narrower escape scope than 'p'.`**

Sometimes the underlying reason for the compiler asserting `CS8157` can be convoluted or hard to see, but the compiler hews to the conservative "better safe than sorry" approach, and this can some­times result in false positives where, for example, you have additional special knowledge that the escape is ultimately contained within the stack.

For cases where `CS8157` is genuinely unwarranted (i.e., in consideration of information that the com­piler wasn't able to infer), these represent the "'perhaps even successful' wily code" examples I alluded to earlier, and generally there's no easy workaround, especially not via `ref struct`. That's because the convoluted false-positives often only arise in higher-level `ref`-passing code scenarios that would never be able to adopt the extreme limitations that are enforced for `ref struct` in the first place.

Instead, `ref struct` is used for very simple value-types. By guaranteeing them that their `this` ref­erence will always be anchored in an upper stack frame--and thus crucially, will never be awash in the GC heap--such types thus gain the confidence to publish managed pointers to themselves or their interiors.

Re­mem­ber, however, that I said `ref struct` is agnostic about how, why, and what the relaxations it provides are used for. What I was specifically alluding to there is that unfortunately, using `ref struct` does not make `CS8157` go away (I consider this a bug, see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/32203) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2107)).

Because `ref struct` code that should properly be allowed to return its own `this` is still prevented by the compiler from doing so, you have to resort to some rather brutish techniques to get around the fatal error(s) when coding within the supposedly liberated `ref struct` instance methods. To wit, value-type instance methods written in **C#** that legitimately need to override fatal errors `CS8170`​/​`CS8157` can **opaque the 'this' pointer** by round-tripping it through an `IntPtr`. This is left as an exercise for the reader, but one way to do this would be via the [System.​Runtime.​CompilerServices.​Unsafe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/) package.

Comment: Nice answer, specially the part **"is not really a feature"** but **"a specific restriction"**.

Comment: How is this different from stackalloc?

Comment: @Brian `stackalloc` is a way to dynamically allocate a contiguous range of temporary memory from the stack on the fly. The element type of a `stackalloc` must be a primitive, so this isn't directly related to `ref struct`, unless you (again, "brutishly") superimpose/overlay/insinuate one or more `ref struct` instance(s) on top of a range of `stackalloc` (e.g.) bytes that you've arranged to be large enough to fit it (or them).

Answer (score 8):

Just adding a bit to the other answer. Basically, they have created a ref struct to be able to hold a managed pointer as a member. This means that it cannot be garbage collected, and if it ever ended up on the heap, the GC would crash. The strange restrictions on what you can and can't do with it are all to do with this (as outlined in the microsoft docs here):

[Microsoft docs on reference semantics in C# 7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types)

All of which is completely fascinating, but doesn't really explain why on earth they've provided this functionality. The real reason was to allow apis that handle both managed and unmanaged memory to have a common interface (i.e. remove the need for endless overloads).

This is explained in detail in this blog:

[Adam Sitnik on Span<T>](http://adamsitnik.com/Span/)

Comment: the name is really misleading. why is it called ref? does it have anything to do with passing struct by reference? if not, should we conceptually just treat it like "stackonly"?

Comment: Exactly the naming is very confusion.. I've been searching for why  Microsoft named it like that couldn't find any  explanation